# Angular 5 required form fields not working with material

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

My first Angular app with Angular 5.

I am following the documentation here: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation. Here is the form that I created:

```
<form class="form-container">
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Shop Name" [(ngModel)]="pizzaPlace.shopName"
           id="shopName" #shopName="ngModel"
           required minlength="4">
  </mat-form-field>
  <div *ngIf="shopName.invalid && (shopName.dirty || shopName.touched)"
       class="alert alert-danger">

    <div *ngIf="shopName.errors.required">
      Shop name is required.
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="shopName.errors.minlength">
      Shop name must be at least 4 characters long.
    </div>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Contact Name" [(ngModel)]="pizzaPlace.contactName"
           id="contactName" #contactName="ngModel"
           required minlength="4">
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

So now if I read the docs correctly, entering and leaving the shop name field will generate an error, but it doesn't seem to be working. I get no indication whatsoever that there's any kind of a problem at all.

Comment: Shouldn't you set a `name` attribute for each input field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Template driven forms need a `name` attribute.

```
<input matInput placeholder="Shop Name" [(ngModel)]="pizzaPlace.shopName"
       id="shopName" #shopName="ngModel"
       required minlength="4"
       name="shopName">
```

https://stackblitz.com/angular/eqormqnlkme

I would recommend strongly to use [reactive forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms), they aren't more difficult to master, but much more powerful.

Also, angular-material provides a built in component for error handling: 
[mat-error](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview#error-messages)

Answer (score 2):

you need to add a  component to display the error

```
 <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Shop Name" [(ngModel)]="pizzaPlace.shopName"
           id="shopName" #shopName="ngModel"
           required minlength="4">
    <mat-error>I said required !</mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: He has `<div *ngIf="shopName.errors.required">
      Shop name is required.
    </div>`. Are you saying that he has to use a specific one for it to even show up?

Comment: @AluanHaddad no your are right, I didnt see the ngIf <....> so with a name attribute it should have worked. But the mat-error is the materialish way of doing this

Comment: Gotcha. It would be nice if it was added automatically though. Oh well.